# Ruby edit and save XML file

Tags: ruby, xml, save, edit

I have written some code to transform the name of the audio files (appending 'XX' to the name on this example). The code is working but I don't find a way to save it as a new xml file. I did try all the solutions I found on the forums but still not working;(

This is a piece of my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xmeml>
<xmeml version="4">
  <sequence authoringapp="Storyboard Pro" 
   projectpath="/Users/rougnaux/Desktop/XML_TEST/man_142_test/man_142_test.sboard" 
    id="man_142_test">
    <media>
     <audio>
        <track>
          <clipitem id="MAN_142_RADIOPLAY - SCRATCH_ESCAPING THE MANOR_20200929">  
            <file id="MAN_142_RADIOPLAY - SCRATCH_ESCAPING THE MANOR_20200929 1">
              <name>MAN_142_RADIOPLAY - SCRATCH_ESCAPING THE MANOR_20200929.wav</name>
            </file>
          </clipitem>
        </track>     
      </audio>
    </media>
    <ismasterclip>FALSE</ismasterclip>
  </sequence>
</xmeml>
```

this is my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

file = File.read('man_142_test.xml')


document  = Nokogiri::XML(file)

document.xpath(("//sequence/media/audio/track/clipitem/file/name")).map {|name| 
 name.children.text }.map!{ |name| 'XX'+name}


File.open("new_test.xml", "w") do |f|
  f.write document.to_xml
end
```

When I check in irb with puts document, I have this output
["XXMAN_142_RADIOPLAY - SCRATCH_ESCAPING THE MANOR_20200929.wav", "XXchimes 02_1.mp3"]
On the 'new_test.xml' file, the name of the audio tracks are not changed. What is missing here?!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
require 'nokogiri'
file = File.read('man_142_test.xml')
document = Nokogiri::XML(file)
document.xpath(("//sequence/media/audio/track/clipitem/file/name")).map do |name|
  name.content = 'XX' + name
end

File.open("new_test.xml", "w") do |f|
  f.write document.to_xml
end
```

Comment: Hello, @user11350468, my "new_test.xml" remains unchanged. now the output of document is : #<Enumerator: [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdc920b4dd0 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdc920adfa8 "MAN_142_RADIOPLAY - SCRATCH_ESCAPING THE MANOR_20200929.wav">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdc920adaf8 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdc920ad580 "chimes 02_1.mp3">]>]:map>

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing same kind of problem, here is the way to do it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

file = File.read('man_142_test.xml')
document = Nokogiri::XML(file)
document.search("//sequence/media/audio/track/clipitem/file/name").each do |node|
  node.content = "XX_#{node.content}"
end


File.open("new_test.xml", "w") do |f|
  f.write document.to_xml
end
```

I think xpath and map were the wrong approaches to modify the xml, even though I don't understand yet why I saw them in lots of solutions about editing xml. If someone can give more details about that, I think it could help lots of people like me!